# Invoke colorbox from a URL (not a link)

Tags: javascript

All of the documentation assumes the content content load into colorbox will happen as a result of click... (e.g., the parameters calling colorbox are built into the link)

> My Example

I want to issue a redirect to a URL that then opens in colobox...

Any suggestions or experience solving this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use java-script and the iframe support in color-box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a", ".the-class-added-to-links-clicking-which-will-open-theurl-in-coloyxbox").click(
      function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var elementURL = $(this).attr("href");
        $.colorbox({iframe: true, href: elementURL, innerWidth: 645, innerHeight: 509});
      });
  });
</script>
```

Code Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933655/493742

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed colorbox module that you don't need to add any library files just use the below code to open lightbox in you custom code

```
<a href="http://hdwallsource.com/img/2014/7/desktop-images-15066-15533-hd-wallpapers.jpg" class="customclass"> Open colorbox </a>

  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("a.customclass").click(
          function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault(); //To prevent redirection
            var hr = jQuery(this).attr("href");
            jQuery.colorbox({iframe: true, href: hr , innerWidth: 500, innerHeight: 400});
          });
      });
 </script>
```

Here href will be link of the page that you want to open in colorbox.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the new URL, you'll need to have javascript on the page to fire the colorbox load event.

Comment: On the page that is being loaded??? It is a URL that calls a function that then loads a page...

Comment: First you need to do the redirect, then you need to open the colorbox. It will require javascript.

Comment: Thank you... It looks like the answer is probably no, you can't, unless you can control the content that you are redirecting to. If the content were a foreign URL, then no. I'm I understanding your answer correctly?

Comment: I was assuming that you controlled the page you were redirecting to...if you don't then the answer is definitely no.